# How to create a list of links?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, terminal

So I have a website links that go like this: site.com/1 site.com/2 site.com/3 etc, up to 1000. How to create a list of this using bash or any programming language on linux? I know the question is most likely duplicate and the answer is probably simple, I just need to add numbers from 1 to 1000 to the value "site.com/" but I couldn't find the answer I need.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to print the links out, all you need is:

```
echo site.com/{1..1000}
```

Or, to have one per line:

```
printf 'site.com/%s\n' {1..1000}
```

If you wish to save the list in an array:

```
sites=(site.com/{1..1000})
# then
for site in "${sites[@]}" ...
```

Comment: Btw. `seq` is another useful command which takes less time but I don't know how to apply in this case.

Comment: @Pandya I don't see how `seq` would be helpful here. Not unless you do something complex like `seq 1 1000 | xargs printf 'site.com/%s\n'` and since we're talking milliseconds here, the speed difference is very unlikely to ever be relevant.

Comment: @Pandya, without seeing benchmark data, I would question your assertion that calling an external command would be faster than using a simple builtin construct.

Comment: @glennjackman actually, I did test, comparing `time printf 'site.com/%s\n' {1..100000} > /dev/null` (real: 0.116s) and `time seq 1 100000 | xargs printf 'site.com/%s\n' > /dev/null` (real: 0.056s) so using seq + xargs might indeed be faster. But, of course, I had to use 2 orders of magnitude more numbers (100000 vs 1000) for the difference to even be quantifiable. And it certainly doesn't seem to outweigh the increased complexity.

Comment: That makes sense. bash would generate the entire list and store it in memory, while seq would just stream it